# How to clear text in MessageKit inputBar after Pressing Send in inputBarAccessoryView

Tags: ios, messagekit, inputbaraccessoryview

I'm building a real time chat application. Where I use message kit and inputBarAccessoryView library to make a conversation between 2 users.

I've used -

```
extension ChatViewController: InputBarAccessoryViewDelegate {
 func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {
  // message sending logic
 }
}
```

this delegate function but when I pressed send button the message is sent but the text is still remain in the inputBar it is not getting cleared.

How can I clear the inputBar text when user click the Send Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution in [this question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034974/messagekit-not-showing-message-input-bar-swift-5).

Adding this line -

```
inputBar.inputTextView.text = ""
```

at the end of the `func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String)` function clears the text after clicking send button.

```
extension ChatViewController: InputBarAccessoryViewDelegate {
func inputBar(_ inputBar: InputBarAccessoryView, didPressSendButtonWith text: String) {
  // all the message sending logic

  // last line
  inputBar.inputTextView.text = ""
 }
}
```